# Writing huge data in JSON format

Tags: json, perl

I need to write data to a file using JSON format. After a bit of research I tried the following code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use JSON::XS;

my $count = 1;
my $nameExp;
my $numExp;
my $maps = [];

open my $out, '>', 'D:/Test.json';

my $json = JSON::XS->new->pretty(1)->utf8;

for (0..999999) {

   $numExp = "";
   for (0..9) {
      $numExp = $numExp.(int(rand(9)));
   }

   $nameExp = "";
   for (0..7) {
      $nameExp = $nameExp.(chr(int(rand(25) + 65)));
   }

   push @$maps, {ID => "$count", Name => "$nameExp", Number => "$numExp"};

   $count++;
}

print $out $json->encode({data => $maps});
```

My problems are

1. If the keys (columns inside the map like `ID`, `Name`, `Number`, etc.) or the no of data (currently 1M) increases, it will result in `Out of memory!`.
2. Pushing the data into the array itself is taking a lot of time. Then I have to write it to the file. Is it possible to write it directly while maintaining the correct format?

I have tried to write it directly instead of pushing it in array but the format is not valid one.

my required sample JSON is like the one below,

```
{
  "data": [
     {
        "ID": "1",
        "Name": "XXXXXX",
        "Number": "7670418426",
     },
     {
        "ID": "2",
        "Name": "YYYYYYY",
        "Number": "4421450424"
     }
  ]
}
```

any suggestions or solutions?

Comment: I was going to recommend adding `use strict;`. It is a good idea, but your code works with `use strict;use warnings;` anyway.

Comment: Although I will ask - why do you need such a large single JSON object?  This I think is the root of your problem - it's a large data structure that you're trying to build in memory.

Comment: A bit of a hack, but you can `print $out $json->encode({ID => $count, Name => $nameExp, Number => $numExp});` and manually take care of `{data => []}`

Comment: That'd be my first though, but it seems dirty. `JSON::XS` supports incremental parsing, but it doesn't seem to support incremental encoding.

Comment: `JSON::XS`is faster one !

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could encode each element of the array separately within the loop and write it to disk immediately. That requires a separate header and footer to be printed literally, and the commas between the elements must be introduced manually

This program creates a smaller sample size of ten, but there are no problems with scaling as the data is stored on disk instead of in memory

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON::XS;

my $json_file = 'D:/Test.json';

open my $out, '>', $json_file
    or die qq{Unable to open "$json_file" for input: $!};
select $out;

print qq<{ "data": [\n>;

my $json = JSON::XS->new->pretty( 1 )->utf8;

my $count;
for ( 1 .. 10 ) {

    my $num_exp  = join '', map { int rand 10 } 1 .. 10;
    my $name_exp = join '', map { chr ord( 'A' ) + rand( 26 ) } 1 .. 8;

    print ', ' if $count;
    print $json->encode( { ID => ++$count, Name => $name_exp, Number => $num_exp } );
}

print qq<] }\n>;
```

#### output

```
{ "data": [
{
   "Name" : "FQAJEWAL",
   "ID" : 1,
   "Number" : "6144230076"
}
, {
   "Number" : "4802605879",
   "Name" : "KKEBKUMZ",
   "ID" : 2
}
, {
   "Number" : "0843901915",
   "Name" : "SGBGIIAS",
   "ID" : 3
}
, {
   "Number" : "2255081597",
   "ID" : 4,
   "Name" : "ZJOPKMPP"
}
, {
   "Number" : "5392332416",
   "Name" : "DXHVGHGQ",
   "ID" : 5
}
, {
   "ID" : 6,
   "Name" : "HAYWEFWR",
   "Number" : "2727718733"
}
, {
   "ID" : 7,
   "Name" : "DIXEBUHW",
   "Number" : "9519451391"
}
, {
   "ID" : 8,
   "Name" : "LWIWIOTV",
   "Number" : "9892199187"
}
, {
   "ID" : 9,
   "Name" : "LJWFVEYC",
   "Number" : "4028143002"
}
, {
   "Name" : "ARNCHOXK",
   "ID" : 10,
   "Number" : "2550291006"
}
] }
```

---

#### Update

It is much easier to assemble YAML data correctly. Here's an equivalent program that generates the YAML equivalent

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $yaml_file = 'D:/Test.yaml';
open my $out, '>', $yaml_file
    or die qq{Unable to open "$yaml_file" for input: $!};
select $out;

print "---\n";
print "data:\n";

my $count;
for ( 1 .. 10 ) {

    my $num_exp  = join '', map { int rand 10 } 1 .. 10;
    my $name_exp = join '', map { chr ord( 'A' ) + rand( 26 ) } 1 .. 8;

    printf "- { ID: %d, Name: %s, Number: %s }\n", ++$count, $name_exp, $num_exp;
}
```

#### output

```
---
data:
- { ID: 1, Name: UOCBQUTN, Number: 8349775867 }
- { ID: 2, Name: DXGMGTXH, Number: 3496217665 }
- { ID: 3, Name: JABBDZLQ, Number: 4207644646 }
- { ID: 4, Name: LWUJPOVY, Number: 5785602496 }
- { ID: 5, Name: JGYEGFDH, Number: 5056633664 }
- { ID: 6, Name: FUJKTBHF, Number: 6657427320 }
- { ID: 7, Name: NAKMJZRS, Number: 1318423549 }
- { ID: 8, Name: QXFDHPHP, Number: 1500434568 }
- { ID: 9, Name: BINACIAB, Number: 5759930882 }
- { ID: 10, Name: JSLNUXQE, Number: 9072575068 }
```

Comment: I'd reached much the same conclusion. Although I had started going with using `JSON` to format me an empty `data` array, I had got slightly tripped up by the need for omitting the last comma.

Comment: it took double the time to generate for **`1M`** data

Comment: @lazy: Yes, that's because of all the calls to `encode`. I was thinking only of getting around the `Out of memory!` error. If you're going for this technique then you would probably be better off using YAML instead of JSON. I've added an alternative solution to my post that will probably be very much faster